# is it possible to drop a column containing a specific value using unix?

Tags: dataframe, unix, awk

I have a very large variant calling data. I can not pull out the result I want.
here is an example

```
bac1 bac2 bac3 bac4
1    0    0    1
```

Now I want to drop the columns that contain 0 using the ubuntu command-line. The result would be like this

```
bac1    bac4
1       1
```

I tried this

```
awk -F "\t" -v "pat=0\t" 'NR == 2 {for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) Take[i] = (pat !=  $i)}{for (i =1; i <= NF; i++) if (Take [i]) printf $i FS; print ""}'
```

And the output is this:

```
NC_045512.2 18876   NC_045512.2_18876_T_C   T   C   .   PASS    GT  1
```

Header of this output is:

```
  #CHROM    POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  FORMAT  EPI_ISL_422804
```

So the final output had to be like this:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  FORMAT  EPI_ISL_422804
NC_045512.2 18876   NC_045512.2_18876_T_C   T   C   .   PASS    GT  1
```

The file is not always 2 lines but at most it can be 4 lines.

It does not return the header line that's because I used NR == 2. Is there any way I cant get the header column as well??

Comment: I would: 1. Transpose input. 2. with grep filter lines with `0`. 3. Transpose input again. `And the output is this:` How is it possible to get such output from `bac1 bac2 bac3 bac4`? Is this s a copy&paste error? Did  you copied some unrelated data? `Is there any way I cant get the header column as well??` `NR==1{print} NR==2{...}`

Comment: Is this always a file with exactly two lines? If not, should we omit columns where all the values are zero?

Comment: @shelter no, that wouldn't print the modified header line and it delete rows/lines that contain a `0` rather than deleting columns that contain a `0`.

Comment: Not sure why this is gathering downvotes - it has a description of the problem, sample input, expected output and the OPs attempt to solve the problem themselves. Yes, it also has some unrelated actual output and it's not clear if the input file is always 2 lines or could be more but the important components of the question are present, we've worked with far less and the OPs only been a member for 2 days and this is their first post!

Comment: the actual data is the parsed variant calling output of 57000 sars-cov-2 genomes. That is I could not provide actual data. then, Bac1 bac2 bac3 bac4 are the example header of the columns and I want the columns with value "0" to be dropped. bac2 and bac3 in the example have value 0 so should be dropped. Last, of all I am new here, that's why I could not arrange the question properly. @KamilCuk

Comment: Mostly two lines file but with first-line as header and second-line contain the value. But sometimes it can be 4 lines depending on mutations in genome @tripleee

Comment: Please note the 2 L s in my identifier ;-) Cheers and good luck to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input file always only has 1 data line as in your example then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 { split($0,hdr); next }
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i != 0) {
            cols[++nf] = i
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= nf; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", hdr[cols[i]], (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= nf; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(cols[i]), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
bac1    bac4
1   1
```

otherwise if your input can have more than 1 data line then you need a 2-pass approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == FNR {
    if (NR > 1) {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                zeroCols[i]
            }
        }
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (! (i in zeroCols) ) {
            cols[++nf] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= nf; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(cols[i]), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
bac1    bac4
1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Long version with `if`:

```
awk 'NR==1{
       split($0,array,FS)
     }

     NR==2{
       s=0
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
         if($i!=0){
           if(s==0){
             s=1
             printf("%s",array[i])
           }
           else{
             printf("%s%s",OFS,array[i])
           }
         }
       }
       print ""

       s=0
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
         if($i!=0){
           if(s==0){
             s=1
             printf("%s",$i)
           }
           else{
             printf("%s%s",OFS,$i)
           }
         }
       }
       print ""
     }' FS='\t' OFS="\t" file
```

One line:

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,array,FS)} NR==2{s=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i!=0) {if(s==0) {s=1; printf("%s",array[i])} else {printf("%s%s",OFS,array[i])}}} print ""; s=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!=0){if(s==0){s=1; printf("%s",$i)} else {printf("%s%s",OFS,$i)}}} print ""}' FS='\t' OFS="\t" file
```

Output:

```
bac1    bac4
1       1
```